# Как в зависимости от радио в селекте и чекбоксах менялись данные?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы, например, еслы был выбран "Вариант 1" то в селекте были варианты 80см, 90см, 100см, а если "Вариант 2" то в селекте были варианты 110см, 120см, 130см, и еслы был выбран "Вариант 1" то доступный только 1 чекбокс, а если "Вариант 2" то только 2 чекбокс?

```html
<input type="radio" id="radOne" name="radio" checked>
<label for="radOne">Вариант 1
<input type="radio" id="radOne" name="radio">
<label for="radTwo">Вариант 2

<select>
<option>80см</option>
<option>90см</option>
<option>120см</option>
<option>140см</option>
<option>160см</option>
<option>180см</option>
</select>
  
<input type="checkbox" id="chbOne" >
<label for="chbOne">Стандарт</label>
  
<input type="checkbox" id="chbOne" >
<label for="chbOne">Не стандарт</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = {
  radOne: {
    options: ['80см', '90см', '120см'],
    checkbox: 'chbOne'
  },
  radTwo: {
    options: ['140см', '160см', '180см'],
    checkbox: 'chbTwo'
  }
}

const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

radios.forEach((radio) => {
  radio.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    
    const radioId = e.currentTarget.id;
    
    select.innerHTML = `<option>
      ${data[radioId].options.join('</option><option>')}
    </option>`
    
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
      checkbox.id === data[radioId].checkbox ? checkbox.disabled = false : checkbox.disabled = true;
    });
    
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="radOne" name="radio" checked>
<label for="radOne">Вариант 1
<input type="radio" id="radTwo" name="radio">
<label for="radTwo">Вариант 2

<select>
<option>80см</option>
<option>90см</option>
<option>120см</option>
</select>
  
<input type="checkbox" id="chbOne" >
<label for="chbOne">Стандарт</label>
  
<input type="checkbox" id="chbTwo" disabled >
<label for="chbTwo">Не стандарт</label>
```